# Loop all columns for value in any column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to loop through all columns in a dataframe to find where a "Feature" condition is met in order to alter the FeatureValue. So if my dataframe(df) looks like below:

```
Feature    FeatureValue    Feature2    Feature2Value
    Cat               1         Dog                3
    Fish              2         Cat                1
```

I want to find where Feature=Cat or Feature2=Cat and change FeatureValue and Feature2Value to 20. I tried the below to get started, but am struggling.

```
for column in df:
    if df.loc[df[column] == "Cat"]:
print(column)
```

The solution would look like:

```
Feature    FeatureValue    Feature2    Feature2Value
    Cat              20         Dog                3
    Fish              2         Cat               20
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it :

```
# First we construct a dictionary linking each feature to its value column
feature_value = {'Feature' : 'FeatureValue', 'Feature2' : 'Feature2Value'}

# We iterate over each feature column
for feature in feature_value:
    df.loc[df[feature]=='Cat', feature_value[feature]] = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a wide data structure. To solve your problem in an elegant way, you should convert to a long data structure. I don't know what you are doing with your data, but the long form is often much easier to deal with.

You can do it like this

```
import pandas as np
from itertools import chain

# set up your sample data
dta = {'Feature': ['Cat', 'Fish'], 'FeatureValue': [1, 2], 'Feature2': ['Dog', 'Cat'], 'Feature2Value': [3, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dta)

# relabel your columns to be able to apply method `wide_to_long`
# this is a little ugly here only because your column labels are not wisely chosen
# if you had [Feature1,FeatureValue1,Feature2,FeatureValue2] as column labels,
# you could get rid of this part
columns = ['Feature', 'FeatureValue'] * int(len(df.columns)/2)
identifier = zip(range(int(len(df.columns)/2)), range(int(len(df.columns)/2)))
identifier = list(chain(*identifier))
columns = ['{}{}'.format(i,j) for i, j in zip(columns, identifier)] 
df.columns = columns

# generate result
df['feature'] = df.index
df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Feature', 'FeatureValue'], i='feature', j='id')
```

Now, you converted your data from

```
  Feature  FeatureValue Feature2  Feature2Value
0     Cat             1      Dog              3
1    Fish             2      Cat              1
```

to this

```
           Feature  FeatureValue
feature id                      
0       0      Cat             1
1       0     Fish             2
0       1      Dog             3
1       1      Cat             1
```

This allows you to answer your problem in a single line, no loops:

```
df_long.loc[df_long['Feature'] == 'Cat', 'FeatureValue'] = 20
```

This yields

```
           Feature  FeatureValue
feature id                      
0       0      Cat            20
1       0     Fish             2
0       1      Dog             3
1       1      Cat            20
```

You can easily go back to your wide format using the same method.